# Named Entity Recognition on Spacy for product category like phones , vehicles not recognized

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

The description of NER on spcay implies it has a classified entity as Product ( vehicles, food etc) but they are not recognized at all. Any idea if I am missing anything. I have tried giving simple sentences like.
sample_String = " I use a car", " I use mobile phone", " I eat rice for lunch" etc

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_md
nlp = en_core_web_md.load()
a = nlp(" I eat rice for lunch")
for ent in a.ents:
    print(a.text, a.start_char, a.end_char, a.label_)
```

Output was blank ( no print executed )

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried and what the output was

Comment: import spacy
import en_core_web_md
nlp = en_core_web_md.load()
a = nlp(" I eat rice for lunch")
for ent in a.ents:
    print(a.text, a.start_char, a.end_char, a.label_) and output was blank ( no print executed )

Answer (score 0):

Named Entity Recognition requires Named Entities. "rice, car, phone ..." are nouns and not Named Entities. **Examples of Named Entities are "Galaxy 5, Toyota, Honda, iPhone, etc."**

In other words, Named Entities are similar to proper nouns. Spacy **NER won't work on just nouns** that don't refer to specific models, brands, etc.

Comment: Do you think i can use any default Entity recognition for extracting "car", "phone" etc?